# Disjoint set data structure supporting deletion

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, data-structures

Assume that we have a set of n disjoint nodes {node<sub>1</sub>,node<sub>1</sub>,...,node<sub>n</sub>}

What is the fastest data structure and algorithm for the following 3 operations:

1. Union(x,y): add an un-directed edge between node<sub>x</sub> and node<sub>y</sub>, there can be at most one edge between two nodes.
2. IsConnected(x,y): returns true if node<sub>x</sub> and node<sub>y</sub> are connected directly or indirectly, i.e node<sub>x</sub> and node<sub>y</sub> are in the the same connected component.
3. Un-union(x,y): remove the edge between node<sub>x</sub> and node<sub>y</sub> if it exists.

Disjoint-set is a perfect data structure for the first two operations, but it cannot support the 3rd operation directly. What is the alternative?

If we simulate the process, the first and 3rd operations can be implemented in O(1) but 2nd  operation is O(n), so I would like to see if it is possible to make all three operations run in O(logn) time or less.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Link/cut tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link/cut_tree) may perform these 3 operations in O(log N) time.

You can read about Link/cut tree and related data structures in this book: ["Handbook of Data Structures and Applications"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584884355) (Chapter 35).

Link/cut tree does not allow adding an edge between nodes, that are already (indirectly) connected. If you need "Union(x,y)" operation to support this, the problem becomes more complicated, and you can solve it as dynamic connectivity problem in undirected graphs. (See chapter 36.4 in the same book or [this pdf](http://www.diku.dk/PATH05/CRC-book1.pdf)). In this case insertion/deletion complexity increases to O(log<sup>2</sup> N).

Comment: Great reference! Actually I heard this data structure once but it was difficult for me to understand, I will see if I can get it this time.

Answer (score 7):

[Kaplan, Shafrir and Tarjan](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.13.4443) propose a general technique to add deletion to union-find data structures by incremental rebuilding and show deletion takes O(t_f(n) + t_i(n)) which are the costs for finding and inserting a node, respectively. The general idea is keeping the number of deleted items in each set and rebuilding the set when this number reaches a certain threshold.

[Alstrup ,Gørtz , Rauhe, Thorup and Zwick](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.88.6803) show how to implement deletions in constant time by noting which elements in a tree are *occupied* and which are *vacant* and "tidying up"
the tree after delete operations.